# how to iterate over two set of json key value pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I would like to compare two json values like

```
source1 = 
{ "a" : "value 1",
 "b" : "value to be updated", 
"c" : "value 3",
 "d" : "second value to be updated" 
  }

target = { 
    "a" : "value 1",  
   "b" : "value 2"",    
   "c" : "value 3",  
   "d" : "second 4"}
```

Now , I would like to compare both the **json** which will have same key but values may differ . How can I find the differed value?

My end result should look like :

```
{
"a" : "value 1"
"b" : "value 2"
"c" : "value 3"
"d" : "second4"

}
```

In the code the first set of key:value needs to be compared with second set and if the second set contains different values , then update the key:value and create a third **json** set :

```
import json
source = '{"a" : "value 1","b" : "value to be updated","c" : "value 3","d" : "second value to be updated" }'

target = '{"a": "value1" , "b" : 2 , "c" : "value 3" , "d" : 4}'

jsonload = (json.loads(source))
jsonload1 = (json.loads(target))

for k in jsonload:
    for k in jsonload1:
        if jsonload[k] != jsonload1[k]:
            print("key of" , k ,"not matched in ", k ,jsonload[k],jsonload1[k])
```

output :

> ('key of', u'a', 'not matched in ', u'a', u'value 1', u'value1') ('key
>   of', u'b', 'not matched in ', u'b', u'value to be updated', 2) ('key
>   of', u'd', 'not matched in ', u'd', u'second value to be updated', 4)
>   ('key of', u'a', 'not matched in ', u'a', u'value 1', u'value1') ('key
>   of', u'b', 'not matched in ', u'b', u'value to be updated', 2) ('key
>   of', u'd', 'not matched in ', u'd', u'second value to be updated', 4)
>   ('key of', u'a', 'not matched in ', u'a', u'value 1', u'value1') ('key
>   of', u'b', 'not matched in ', u'b', u'value to be updated', 2) ('key
>   of', u'd', 'not matched in ', u'd', u'second value to be updated', 4)
>   ('key of', u'a', 'not matched in ', u'a', u'value 1', u'value1') ('key
>   of', u'b', 'not matched in ', u'b', u'value to be updated', 2) ('key
>   of', u'd', 'not matched in ', u'd', u'second value to be updated', 4)

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: "I would like to compare two json value" => those are NOT "json values", those are Python dicts. Read the doc for python's dicts and you'll find all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `dict.update()` method

**Ex:**

```
source1 = { "a" : "value 1", "b" : "value to be updated", "c" : "value 3", "d" : "second value to be updated" }
target = { "a" : "value 1", "b" : "value 2", "c" : "value 3", "d" : "second 4"}
source1.update(target)
print(source1)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 'value 1', 'c': 'value 3', 'b': 'value 2', 'd': 'second 4'}
```

Comment: this worked. for me. now i would like to know if source1 keys and target keys are same , if any target has some extra keys , that needs to be specified in a log . how can we achieve that ?